# CSS loading perfectly in Chrome, but not even picked up by Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, get

I've got a pretty bizarre problem, but I've got no clue as to how to solve it, so my apologies for not having as much preceding material as I usually like to have when answering questions.

Essentially I have a very simple site where I've got an image that has height and width set to 100%. CSS file is here:

```
.background{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #6DCFF6;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome as it should, but when I open this in FF and inspect with firebug, the DOM is totally normal, but there is no CSS at all. It's not that it's incorrect or anything, there's just no CSS on anything.

And then the mystery deepened. When I go to localhost there is a successful GET request on the css resource:

```
"[Time] GET /static/css/registration.css HTTP/1.1" 200 97
```

but nothing shows up. I'm at a loss here, I forced a refresh of the CSS cache to no avail. Any ideas? Using FF 23.

Comment: Have you accidentally disabled CSS in FireBug? Does CSS load for other sites?

Comment: @codemonkeh it does indeed load on other sites.

Comment: Do you have ABP extension on Firefox?  Is the CSS in blocked items?  Also check: are you serving your CSS with type `text/css`?

Comment: I do not have that extension, would it help me debug the problem? Also, tried with and without serving as text/css.

Comment: You mean it wasn't being served as `text/css` or it was?  If you've served it with the wrong headers make sure to clear the cache before retrying.  Confirm in the console (Ctrl + Shift + K) what type Firefox thinks it is.

Comment: @robertc I mean I tried it both ways while clearing the cache and it had no effect.

Comment: Upload your files to a server we can access and we can debug further.

Comment: Also make sure that the character sets are OK. Firefox has problems with, for instance, windows-1252 in the HTTP header, but a UTF-8 BOM in the file itself. Then FF will see `ï»¿.background` for the selector, which is incorrect.